# get the value of attribute 'transform' of svg element <use> with JQuery .attr() method

Tags: jquery, svg, attributes

I need to get the value of the 'transfrom' attribute inside the attr method, but it is returning `undefined`.

Look at [my pen with full code](https://codepen.io/flyby/pen/ZLWmva), the code is also below and followed with a Snippet created from that code):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>   
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<style>
#cont {
    width:99vw;
    height:99vh;
}
svg {
    background-color:grey;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#point {
    stroke:none;
    fill:rgba(40,40,40,.9);
    cursor:pointer;
  }
#crown{
    fill:none;
    stroke:rgba(170,250,80,.8);
    stroke-width:3;     
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='cont'>
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<defs>
    <circle cx='80' cy='100' r='25' id='point' transform='translate(0,0)'/>
    <circle cx='80' cy='100' r='35' id='crown' transform='translate(0,0)'/>
</defs>
<g id='useGroup'>
    <use xlink:href='#point' class='pointUse'/>
    <use xlink:href='#point' class='pointUse' transform='translate(150,0)'/>
    <use xlink:href='#crown' class='crownUse' transform='translate(150,0)'/>
</g>
</svg>
</div>
<script>
var v = 0;     
$('.pointUse').click(function() {
    n = $('.pointUse').attr('transform');
    $('.crownUse').attr('transfom', n);
    console.log(n,'test' , v);
    v++;
    //console.log = undefined
});       
</script>
</body>
</xml>
```

```js
$('.pointUse').click(function(e) {
  n = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("transform")
  crown.setAttribute('transform', n);
  console.log('the attribute "transform" value of this <use/> is: ' + n);
});
```

```css
#cont {
  width: 99vw;
  height: 99vh;
}
svg {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#point {
  stroke: none;
  fill: rgba(40, 40, 40, .9);
  cursor: pointer;
}
#crown {
  fill: none;
  stroke: rgba(170, 250, 80, .8);
  stroke-width: 3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='cont'>
  <svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
      <circle cx='80' cy='100' r='25' id='point' transform='translate(0,0)' />
      <circle cx='80' cy='100' r='35' id='crown' transform='translate(0,0)' />
    </defs>
    <g id='useGroup'>
      <use xlink:href='#point' class='pointUse' />
      <use xlink:href='#point' class='pointUse' transform='translate(150,0)' />
      <use xlink:href='#crown' class='crownUse' transform='translate(150,0)' />
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

In accordance with the rules of formatting and for its prompt correction code has been edited. Posted code has been successfully compiled as like the linked 'pen.'

Comment: Please post the relevant "*[mcve]*" code in your question; don't expect us to go to, or rely upon, an external site in order to help you.

Comment: You can use whatever notation style you prefer to use, but bear in mind that it needs to be understandable. But please remember the title of that guideline, it has to be both "*minimal*" (the smallest amount of code necessary to reproduce your problem) and "*complete*" (to accurately recreate your problem). As for your opinion regarding the rules, no: it's so that your question can be understood most easily, by the widest audience even if the external site fails for whatever reason.

Comment: okay, mr David, now all is ok, can i run code inside stackoverflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use an event object and currentTarget to get the clicked use element and standard DOM methods to get/set the transform.

```js
var v = 0;
$('.pointUse').click(function(e) {
  n = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("transform")
  crown.setAttribute('transform', n);
  console.log('the attribute "transform" value of this <use/> is: ' + n);
  v++;
});
```

```css
#cont {
  width: 99vw;
  height: 99vh;
}
svg {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#point {
  stroke: none;
  fill: rgba(40, 40, 40, .9);
  cursor: pointer;
}
#crown {
  fill: none;
  stroke: rgba(170, 250, 80, .8);
  stroke-width: 3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='cont'>
  <svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
      <circle cx='80' cy='100' r='25' id='point' transform='translate(0,0)' />
      <circle cx='80' cy='100' r='35' id='crown' transform='translate(0,0)' />
    </defs>
    <g id='useGroup'>
      <use xlink:href='#point' class='pointUse' transform='translate(0,0)'/>
      <use xlink:href='#point' class='pointUse' transform='translate(150,0)' />
      <use xlink:href='#crown' class='crownUse' transform='translate(0,0)' />
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: great thx Holger Will! It's working!
 Look like ES need  just need more details about function...

Comment: tell me please, is this methond works with jquery .animate()? or this is already  greenSock theme?

Comment: @AleksandrIvanitskiy I think you might need to create a new question if you have an issue with jquery .animate(). Neither of us have used any greenSock in our answers though because there's none in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Seems fine once I correct the code to get the object you're actually clicking on (I think that's your intent here) and not an array of all objects.

```js
var v = 0;
$('.pointUse').click(function() {
  n = $(this).attr('transform');
  console.log('the attribute "transform" value of this <use/> is: ' + n);
  v++;
});
```

```css
#cont {
  width: 99vw;
  height: 99vh;
}
svg {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#point {
  stroke: none;
  fill: rgba(40, 40, 40, .9);
  cursor: pointer;
}
#crown {
  fill: none;
  stroke: rgba(170, 250, 80, .8);
  stroke-width: 3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='cont'>
  <svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
      <circle cx='80' cy='100' r='25' id='point' transform='translate(0,0)' />
      <circle cx='80' cy='100' r='35' id='crown' transform='translate(0,0)' />
    </defs>
    <g id='useGroup'>
      <use xlink:href='#point' class='pointUse' />
      <use xlink:href='#point' class='pointUse' transform='translate(150,0)' />
      <use xlink:href='#crown' class='crownUse' transform='translate(150,0)' />
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```